# How do I tell MapStruct to use a different source if one source is null?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have two objects of different types that are mapped to an object of a third type:

```
@Mapping(target = "color" //how to map this )
public abstract CombinedCar from(BlueBookCar blueBookCar , AutoTraderCar autoTraderCar);
```

- `CombinedCar` has a String field named, `color`.
- `BlueBookCar` has a String field named, `color`.
- `AutoTraderCar` has a String field named, `carColor`.

If `BlueBookCar` has a non-null `color`, I want to use it to set the `color` on `CombinedCar`.

Otherwise, I want to use the `carColor` of `AutoTraderCar` to set the color on `CombinedCar`.

How can configure MapStruct to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an [`@AfterMapping`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html) method that would do the logic and set the `color` value:

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class MyMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "color", ignore = true)
  public abstract CombinedCar from(BlueBookCar blueBookCar, AutoTraderCar autoTraderCar);

  @AfterMapping
  public void mapColor(
      @MappingTarget CombinedCar target, BlueBookCar blueBookCar, AutoTraderCar autoTraderCar) {
    target.setColor(
        blueBookCar.getColor() == null ? autoTraderCar.getColor() : blueBookCar.getColor());
  }
}
```

`@Mapping(target = "color", ignore = true)` is necessary to prevent error below from appearing during the build.

> java: Several possible source properties for target property "color".